# Mr.Developer couldn't find 'git' exec on my path. I have Windows/msysgit

Tags: windows, git, msysgit

I get the error from mr. developer: "Couldn't find 'git' executable on your PATH."

I'm running msysgit on Windows 7 and I believe I have the latest Mr. Developer. Any ideas?

Comment: the error message is quite clear, it cannot find git on your path, add it on your path. http://geekswithblogs.net/renso/archive/2009/10/21/how-to-set-the-windows-path-in-windows-7.aspx

Answer (score 3):

You could copy git.exe to git with no file extension ,then the problem could be solved. The clue is found by the link provided by Chis.

Answer (score 1):

For my case, I use the portable version of msysgit since I wanted full control of the set up and installation.

In README.portable, you'll read the following

> ### How to start using PortableGit
>
> If you are comfortable with a Unix-like shell, just launch
>   'git-bash.bat'.
>
> If not, just launch 'git-cmd.bat'.
>
> Alternatively, you can execute these commands to modify the %path%
>   variable temporarily:
>
> ```
>     set gitdir=c:\portablegit
>     set path=%gitdir%\cmd;%path%
> ```
>
> Adjust the 'gitdir' according to your setup.  As long as you do not
>   close the command window, you can now simply type "git" or "gitk" to
>   really call "c:\portablegit\cmd\git.cmd" or
>   "c:\portablegit\cmd\gitk.cmd".

Personally, I run the shell by invoking `git-cmd.bat` so that I'll gain access on unix commands, like `ls`, `mv`, etc.

Answer (score 0):

Make sure your System PATH includes your msysgit directory, assuming you've [installed and built](https://github.com/msysgit/msysgit/wiki/InstallMSysGit) it correctly.

Comment: I think I've added it correctly. 'C:\Program Files (x86)\Git' is at the end of my PATH.

Comment: Ok, I found more paths I had to add here: http://code.google.com/p/msysgit/source/browse/git-cmd.bat. I added the bin and the cmd directories and now it seems to work.